# Setting up Mobile JUnit tests to run under JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, java-me, junit

I'm using Mobile JUnit, released by Sony Ericsson for unit testing for my J2ME project. I read in the documentation that one can run the tests under regular junit with the help of a few wrapper classes. The documentation, in fact, recommends that you do this if you want to generate reports for CI builds, etc. which is exactly what I want.

Unfortunately, the documentation is a little terse on how to do this. Has anyone had any luck with this aspect of Mobile JUnit?

Comment: Actually, I gave up. I now have an ant build script that compiles to J2SE to run the junit tests and compiles to run it as J2ME MIDlet. I use the microemulator to get the J2ME classes to compile on J2SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did (and I'm not saying this is necessarily a good idea in general, but it worked in my specific case) was to separate the the code base into a library and the UI.  The library didn't include an J2ME specific stuff in it and it didn't include anything that J2SE had the J2ME didn't.  As a result, you could check it out in NetBeans as a J2SE project and it would compile.  Then I wrote JUnit tests in the J2SE context.  This doesn't help test the UI, but it made it very easy to test the library.

It sounds like you found a more complete solution that tests both.  Can you elaborate on what microemulator you used?

Comment: I used the one at http://www.microemu.org/. The docs aren't the greatest in the world and you can't emulate everything; I had to change the way I used RecordStore to get the tests to work. But if you put that jar in your classpath when you run the tests, it works quite effectively.